# gsub! Is modifying unspecified strings

Tags: ruby

I'm extracting some information from an XML file, and I want to perform some modifications on the data while keeping a copy of the original in a variable "origFile". This is what I have:

```
require "rexml/document"
include REXML

doc = Document.new File.new(thePath)
root = doc.root 
array = []
root.elements.each("dict/string") {|element| array << element}

origFile = []
root.elements.each("dict"){|i| origFile << i}

theBody = array[6][0].to_s

theBody.gsub!(/\&lt;!-- more --\&gt;/, "----------Read More----------")
```

The problem is that after I perform gsub! on theBody, origFile also has the modification. I don't understand why this would be or how to fix it. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just this:

```
theBody = array[6][0].to_s.dup
```

Without the `.dup`, both of your variables are referring to the same string. With it, theBody gets a separate  copy.

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the string in place, which means that you are also modifying any other reference to that string. If you only want `theBody` to be modified, use `dup` to copy the string and create a new instance of it:

```
theBody = array[6][0].to_s.dup
theBody.gsub!(/\&lt;!-- more --\&gt;/, "----------Read More----------")
```

You could also just use `gsub` (without the `!`):

```
theBody = array[6][0].to_s
theBody = theBody.gsub(/\&lt;!-- more --\&gt;/, "----------Read More----------")
```

I would recommend this:

```
theBody = array[6][0].to_s.
  gsub(/\&lt;!-- more --\&gt;/, "----------Read More----------")
```